# Application Composition in Software-Defined Networking (SDN)

Tags: composition, sdn

I have seen that many current SDN controller platforms like OpenDaylight, Floodlight or the HP VAN SDN controller allow to write SDN applications as independent modules. It seems like you can run multiple applications side by side. With the HP SDN app store it even seems like you can easily compose applications from different vendors. Since different applications may in general not be aware of each other, I wonder what happens when two applications specify conflicting policies? For example, one application is responsible for isolating certain hosts in the network while another application is responsible for forwarding traffic. If the forwarding application is not aware of the isolation, it could theoretically violate the isolation policy.

I stumbled across the topic of Network Intent Composition in OpenDaylight. As far as I could see from talks held at last year’s OpenDaylight Summit, it contains at least a simple conflict resolution mechanism. Is there another mechanism available in OpenDaylight? What about the other platforms like Floodlight, the HP VAN SDN controller or other controller platforms in general? Especially I would like to know how it is handled in the HP VAN SDN controller when using the app store. It seems like Network Intent Composition is a contribution of HP. Is HP using a similar technique in their own SDN controller platform (if at all)?

Answer (score 0):

Floodlight modules handle packetIns in a pipeline model.  When you create a module, there is a pair of methods that define the ordering:

isCallbackOrderingPrereq()
isCallbackOrderingPostreq()

If you take the forwarding module as an example, you can see that it is after topology manager, device manager, and firewall and it checks whether any routing decision has been made earlier to decide what to do.

So, you will write the module however logic you want to resolve such conflicts.